# It looks like Capybara clicked on button properly, but doesn't proceed to the next page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, cucumber, capybara

I have problem with writing Cucumber tests. After payment via Paylane(somehow there is only problem with Paylane scenarios; Paypal, Stripe and Payu works fine) when its on 'Thank You' page it looks like Capybara click on button(to return to store) it's get highlighted in browser but it doesn't do anything. Moreover it goes to the next step and check if its whether on store page so it thinks that clicking on button went well(I suppose). Can someone help me with that?

```
@lp @purchase @paylane @javascript
Feature: Purchase a product from a Landing Page via Paylane
  As a Sneakpick user
  I can access Landing Pages of product
  So I can successfully purchase it via Paylane

  Scenario: Purchase product via Paylane # features/purchases/landing_page/paylane.feature:7
    Given I visit the Landing Page       # features/step_definitions/basic_steps.rb:5
    Then I want to order 1 product       # features/step_definitions/purchase_steps.rb:92
    And product is available via Paylane # features/step_definitions/purchase_steps.rb:1
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a template handler in the template name is deprecated. You can simply remove the handler name or pass render :handlers => [:erb] instead. (called from _app_views_paylane_pay_html_erb___1015711955565910954_70249561011280 at /home/szczepan/1000i/Git/sneakpick/app/views/paylane/pay.html.erb:2)
    Then I go to payment                 # features/step_definitions/purchase_steps.rb:53
    And I pay via Paylane                # features/step_definitions/paylane_steps.rb:1
      expected to find text "Product" in "Payment - Sneakpick.co Thank You! Your order has been processed. We've sent you a confirmation emailwith your order details. « Back to product powered by sneakpick" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/purchase_steps.rb:77:in `/^I am on Landing page$/'
      ./features/step_definitions/paylane_steps.rb:2:in `/^I pay via Paylane$/'
      features/purchases/landing_page/paylane.feature:12:in `And I pay via Paylane'
    And my Paylane order should be made  # features/step_definitions/paylane_steps.rb:76

  Scenario: Purchase product via Paylane             # features/purchases/landing_page/paylane.feature:15
    Given I visit the Landing Page                   # features/step_definitions/basic_steps.rb:5
    Then I want to order 1 product                   # features/step_definitions/purchase_steps.rb:92
    And product is available via Paylane             # features/step_definitions/purchase_steps.rb:1
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a template handler in the template name is deprecated. You can simply remove the handler name or pass render :handlers => [:erb] instead. (called from _app_views_paylane_pay_html_erb___1015711955565910954_70249561011280 at /home/szczepan/1000i/Git/sneakpick/app/views/paylane/pay.html.erb:2)
    Then I go to payment                             # features/step_definitions/purchase_steps.rb:53
    And I pay via Paylane not with card successfully # features/step_definitions/paylane_steps.rb:13
    And my Paylane order should be made              # features/step_definitions/paylane_steps.rb:76
```

Oh, and second one works fine, but first one don't and yet they click on the same button.
Here are the steps:

```
And /^I pay via Paylane$/ do
  steps %(
    And I check if Paylane form is filled with correct data
    And I fill in the card data
    And I send form
    And I accept confirmation alert
    And I am on Thank You page
    And I click 'Back to product' button
    And I am on Landing page
  )
end

And /^I pay via Paylane not with card successfully$/ do
  steps %(
    And I choose last available payment
    And I send form
    And I accept confirmation alert
    And I click 'SUCCESS' button
    And I am on Thank You page
    And I click 'Back to product' button
    And I am on Landing page
  )
end
```

And "I click (.+) button" step:

```
And /^I click '(.+)' button$/ do |button|
    click_on(button)
end
```

The button contains text "Back to product".

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've added sleeps before clicking that were causing troubles and it helps, but I'm treating this like a temporary solution. Is there troubles with cucumber to wait until the page is loaded before doing stuff on it?

Answer (score 0):

One of the typical solutions for this (at least in Ruby-Cucumber) is a simple method like `wait_for_ajax` - basically, it blocks until it registers that there's no more active HTTP calls before continuing on. This is usually done inside Capybara as a function call from your step definition. Whenever you expect to have to wait (especially on a third-party page), sprinkle this liberally throughout your step-defs, especially after you take an action (like clicking on something). It's far more dependable than just calling `sleep()` for a predetermined amount of time.

```
def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
        loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
    end
end

def finished_all_ajax_requests?
    page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
end
```

Source: [Thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara) for original source code (it's been a while) and personal experience fixing an unreliable Capybara/Cucumber test suite.

Also, last I checked, the `steps%(...)` syntax in Capybara is deprecated, and you should call individual steps with `step '...'` instead. It lets you treat your step-defs more like function calls (for exactly this kind of thing).